# How to lock an object during a distributed transaction

Tags: microservices, distributed-transactions

I have been reading about microservices and distributed transactions. Most articles talk about 2 Phase commit or Saga pattern, but does not go into detail on how an object is locked, so that other can't access that data when the transaction has not completed.

if I have a customer service and an order service and I initiate a request to lock customers funds till the order has been processed. In a distributed system, how is this achieved.

In DB's is it possible to explicitly lock a row and then another request goes and unlocks the row or is this achieved using a locked field on the customers table that the first transaction sets it to locked and once the order is complete, it goes back and sets it to unlocked or empties that row?

If there are some examples with code samples that will be great

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is 2-phase commit not suitable for a microservices architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55249656/why-is-2-phase-commit-not-suitable-for-a-microservices-architecture)

Answer (score 2):

> Most articles talk about 2 Phase commit or Saga pattern, but does not
>   go into detail on how an object is locked, so that other can't access
>   that data when the transaction has not completed.

The 2PC is defined as blocking. That means that if transaction manager, which manages the 2PC transaction, is down the 2PC can't be resolved. The transaction manager is then a single point of failure.
If you are ensured that a failed transaction manager is restarted then even the 2PC protocol is said to be blocking you are the assurance that transaction manager will be available and the resolution won't be blocked.

Then 2PC uses locks. They are required as a fundamental element of the protocol. Transaction manager communicates with participants - resources. The participant is the database. When the 2PC starts running then the call of prepare means that the database makes a persistent locks on all rows that participated in the transaction. This lock is released when transaction manager calls commit.
It's important to understand that the transaction before the 2PC is in-flight (not persistent). It's stored in-memory. After the prepare is called the transaction state is stored persistently, until commit is called (and at that time the protocol may be blocked by unavailable transaction manager - the lock is persistent and the system waits for the transaction manager to do release it).

That's about locking from the 2PC perspective. But there are transaction locks from database perspective.
When you update a row in database then the transaction is in-flight (stored in memory). At that time the database needs to ensure that concurrent updates won't corrupt your data. One way is to lock the row and do not permit the concurrent updates.
But, the most databases do not lock the row - by default, in dependence to isolation level - in these cases as they use snapshot isolation (MVCC, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_isolation). That particularly means that the row is locked optimistically and the database permits other transactions to update the row.

But! the 2PC prepare can't be processed optimistically. When the database replies 'OK' to prepare request from the transaction manager the row is just locked.

Plus, you can't manage this locking by hand. If you try to do so you ruin the 2PC guarantee of consistency.

As in your example there is a customer service and an order service. When the 2PC transaction spans over the both services. Then customer updates database and order service updates the database as well. There is still running in-flight transactions in the database. Then request finishes and transaction manager commands the in-flight transaction to commit. It runs the 2PC. It invokes prepare on the customer service db transaction, then on the order service transaction and then it calls to commit.

If you use the saga pattern then saga is span over the both services. From the transaction perspective the customer service creates a database in-flight transaction and it commits it immediately. Then the call goes to the order service where the same happens too. When the request finishes the saga checks that everything run fine. When a failure happened a compensate callback is called.

The failure is "the trouble" from the perspective of ease of use. For saga you need to maintain the failure resolution on your own in the callback method. For 2PC the failure resolution is processed automatically by rollback call.

A note: I tried to summarized the 2PC here: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/TwoPhaseCommit2PC
I'm not truly sure if the explanation is comprehensible enough but you can try to check. And you may let me know what's wrongly explained there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the micro-services world the transaction boundaries are within a service. The services rely on eventual consistency. So in your example the Order service will send a request(Synchronous or Asynchronous depending on application semantics and scale requirements) like *Deduct x amount from customer y for order z*.

The customer service would do the action on customer record in a transaction and return response to the customer like *Order z successfully processed* or *Order z processing failed*.

The order service can then trigger the confirmation/failure process of the order depending on response received.

The application typically choose between availability and ACID strong consistency. Most microservice based scenarios demand availability and high scalability as opposed to strong consistency, which means the communication between services is asynchronous and consistent state is eventually achieved.